# Get data from cell with spilled data from excel using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet that has `=STOCKHISTORY("A",TODAY()-5*365,TODAY(),0)` in A1, and it spills from A1 to B1258. I am trying to get the data from B2 to B1258 to use python to run a algorithm on the data. I have been using openpylx, I have come up with

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = r"filepath.xlsm")


for sheet in wb:
    if sheet.title != 'SNP500': 
        cells = []
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row = 2, min_col = 2, max_col = 2, values_only=True):
            cells.append(row)
        
    if sheet.title == 'A':
        break
print(cells)
```

When I run this I get

```
[('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',), ('=',)]
```

The excel sheet looks like
[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FG7M.png)
Thank you

Comment: In the first line where you load up the workbook, try adding "data_only=True"

Comment: Thank you, I have been working on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the cells you are reading contain the formula of that cell, not the result of the formula (Excel formulas usually start with "=").
To fix this, when you load the workbook add `data_only=True` as a parameter

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename="foo.xlsx", data_only=True)
```